# Hibernate Criteria: nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying get all data from isssue table that matches with projectname and Issue Id. I'm getting following error. please help me.

Tables
**Project**
ProjectID
ProjectName

**Issue**
issueID
identifier
sourceStatus
title
severity
description

**Project.java**

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="project")
    public class Project implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2457316470957669814L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="ProjectId")
        private Integer projectId;

        @Column(name="projectname")
        private String projectName;

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "project")
        private List<Issue> issue;

        //getters and setters
    }
```

**Issue.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="issue")
public class Issue implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private Integer Id;

    @Column(name="identifier")
    private String identifier;

    @Column(name="sourcestatus")
    private String sourceStatus;

    @Column(name="severity")
    private Integer severity;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="ProjectId")
    private Project project;

//getters and setters
  }
```

**IssueDAOImpl.java**

```
public List<Issue> getAllIssue(String identifier,String projectName) {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Issue.class);
    criteria.createAlias("Project", "Prj");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("identifier",identifier));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Prj.projectName",projectName));

    List<Issue> list=criteria.list();
    return list;
}
```

**CONSOLE**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dcm] in context with path [/SearchTool] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Project of: com.dcm.search.bean.Issue] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Project of: com.dcm.search.bean.Issue
```

Comment: Please can you post the contents of the ArchivalIssue class?

Comment: @Hedley sorry I edited the post. It's Issue Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `criteria.createAlias("Project", "Prj")` to `criteria.createAlias("project", "Prj")`. The property for which you are trying to create an alias is **project**, so should go as the first argument of `createAlias`. **Project** is the class name.

Comment: Still I'm not able to fetch data. But I'm not getting any error.

Comment: Can you set the 'show_sql' property of hibernate to true and run the generated sql on the database?

Comment: Thank you so much. :) But I'm not getting unique values. Getting duplicate entry for each issue in project :(

Comment: Does the sql give you duplicates?

Comment: yes, I was getting duplicate values from SQL. I used setResultTransformer to get unique values. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have called the Hibernate property "ProjectId", not "Project".

```
criteria.createAlias("Project", "Prj");
```

This should be:

```
criteria.createAlias("ProjectId", "Prj");
```

Comment: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: projectId of: com.dcm.search.bean.Issue